# Facebook Open Graph article:author links to wrong person

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, author

I use Facebook Opengrah tags:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="605862"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="PhillyGayCalendar.com"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="Is Gay Media Insensitive to the Trans Experience?"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://phillygaycalendar.com/pages/col.php?id=943"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://phillygaycalendar.com/Connections/thumb.php?src=http://phillygaycalendar.com/images/columns/943.jpg&h=292&w=560&zc=1&a=t"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="article " />
<meta property="article:publisher" content="https://www.facebook.com/phillygaycalendar" />
<meta property="article:author" content="https://www.facebook.com/MrLovehall" />
```

When I post the link to facebook, it shows the wrong author. It lists me (who is the admin) but not MrLoveHall who is the author or the piece.

Original Link: http://phillygaycalendar.com/pages/col.php?id=943

Am I doing it wrong? How do I fix it

Comment: [FB debug tool says](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fphillygaycalendar.com%2Fpages%2Fcol.php%3Fid%3D943), _“The meta tag on the page was specified with name 'author', which matches a configured property of this object type. It will be ignored unless specified with the meta property attribute instead of the meta name attribute.”_ – you have `<META NAME='AUTHOR' CONTENT='Steve McCann'>` further down there in the page, and that’s probably what this message is referring to – so try and remove that, and see what the debug tool says then.

Comment: Your HTML is pretty broken (`meta`/`link` before `html`, DOCTYPE after `head`, two `head` elements etc.).

Comment: Same issue here. Do you have a solution for it?

[My Post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28703102/facebook-sharer-showing-almost-always-the-wrong-author

Answer (score 0):

Ran across this three years later, and want to point out that CBroe's answer is correct.  Not sure why it wasn't listed as solved since it does seem the target page has been corrected with that answer.    On the page now is:

```
<meta property="article:author" content="https://www.facebook.com/MrLovehall" />
<meta name="author" content="Christian Axavier Lovehall" />
```

Facebook debugger is complaining that you have author specified in two ways and it only accepts the article:author and displays warning for author.