# Facebook sharer showing (almost) always the wrong author

Tags: wordpress, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, author

I can't understand why Facebook sharer keeps showing the wrong article's author when sharing articles of my website. (Of course I always use Facebook Debugger before sharing).

Take this [article](http://wordsinthebucket.com/u-turn-indonesia-virginity-tests) as an example: although it is clearly written by Francesca Aloisio, it keeps showing (when shared) "by Virginia Vigliar".

Facebook Debugger reports:

```
<meta property="article:publisher" content="https://www.facebook.com/wordsinthebucket" />
<meta property="article:author" content="https://www.facebook.com/francesca.aloisio.397" />
```

I just can't figure out why.

N.B. I use Wordpress SEO by Yoast.

Comment: The author is showing properly for me, when I share...Interesting.

Comment: Same here. Preview reads "By Francesca Aloisio". Nevertheless there are a few warnings regarding duplicate og tags and unexpected order of tags ...

Answer (score 1):

Why are you having the og values defined **twice**?

Have a look at below (line 23 to line 47):

```
<!--Facebook Open Graph-->
<!--FB page title-->
<meta property="og:title" content="Indonesia Makes a Sharp U-turn on Virginity Tests" />
<!--FB description-->
<meta property="og:description" content="Most students in the world may think that in order to get their high school diploma they would have to meet certain requirements: good grades, good attitude towards school, good relationship with teac..."/>
<!--FB url-->
<meta property="og:url" content="http://wordsinthebucket.com/u-turn-indonesia-virginity-tests"/>
<!--FB image-->
<meta property="og:image" content="http://wordsinthebucket.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/indonesia-exam.jpg" />
<!--FB type-->
<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
<!--FB site name-->
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Words in the Bucket"/>

<!-- This site is optimized with the Yoast SEO plugin v2.3.5 - https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/ -->
<title>Indonesia Makes a Sharp U-turn on Virginity Tests</title>
<meta name="description" content="Indonesian officials were forced to take a step back on their proposal of introducing virginity tests for high schoolgirls."/>
<link rel="canonical" href="http://wordsinthebucket.com/u-turn-indonesia-virginity-tests" />
<link rel="publisher" href="https://plus.google.com/+WiBTeam/about"/>
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Indonesia Makes a Sharp U-turn on Virginity Tests" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Indonesian officials were forced to take a step back on their proposal of introducing virginity tests for high schoolgirls." />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://wordsinthebucket.com/u-turn-indonesia-virginity-tests" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Words in the Bucket" />
```

Remove either one of them, because this is causing the FB Debugger to show that:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
<meta name="author" content="[THE_AUTHOR_HERE]">
```

also plus removing the duplication and then going here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ insert the url and press "fetch new scrape information" and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: thank you all for your replies. However in the meanwhile I changed my theme cause I realized that it was an issue related to my previous one: it had a "top post" part at the very beginning of the page and the first post showed in there was seen by the FB sharer as the meta "source".

Regarding the double og values, thank for noticing. My actual theme appearently has its own "SEO". So I just removed it from the header.php file and keep YOAST SEO doing the job.